# Guava event subscribing in any place i want (java,kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin, events, event-handling, guava

I needed events in my application. I want to be able to subscribe to events in any class (or not in a class because I'm using Kotlin) but guava eventbus seems to allow you to subscribe to events only in objects that are registered via

> `EventManager.register(SomeObject)`

I tried doing this

> `EventManager.register(Any())`

but it doesn't work. How do I subscribe to events if I don't want to register objects
?

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  You will need to use some other structure, like a `SharedFlow` -- though even there, you will have to create a subscription to the flow.

Comment: wow, that sad :(

Comment: What's so bad about creating objects?